# SQL Output with multi join on different rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to join 2 different data sets with different columns and when I make the join I get repeated results.

My input dataset1 with actual data:

```
Cust_id  Year  sales
----------------------
1        2016  679862
1        2017  705365
1        2018  195662
1        2019  201234
2        2016   51074
2        2017   50611
2        2018   19070
2        2019   20123
```

My input dataset2 with estimated data:

```
Cust_id  Year  salesest
-------------------------
1        2018  779862
1        2019  125662
2        2017   23456
2        2018   32856
2        2019   26602
```

Desired output:

```
Cust_id  Year  sales  salesest
-------------------------------
1        2016  679862  null
1        2017  705365  null
1        2018  195662  779862
1        2019  201234  125662
2        2016   51074  null
2        2017   50611   23456
2        2018   19070   32856
2        2019   20123   26602
```

This is what I have tried:

```
select 
    a.*, b.salesest
from 
    tab1 a, tab2 b
where
    a.Cust_id = b.Cust_id
```

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: left join isnt helping here we need distinct of salesest

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you also need to specify the year - and make an outer join for the times when there is no corresponding year in the other table.

```
select a.*, b.salesest
frpm tab1 a, tab2 b
where
a.Cust_id=b.Cust_id
AND a.YEAR = b.YEAR (+)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want a `LEFT JOIN`.  The correct syntax is:

```
select a.*, e.salesest
from actuals a left join
     estimates e
     on a.Cust_id = e.Cust_id and
        a.year = e.year;
```